# Gradle: Include project with buildscript as sub-project

Tags: gradle

I have the following problem: there is project with its own buildscript section:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }   
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlinVersion"
    }   
}
```

when i include it as a sub-project into the other one (also having similar buildscript section) i get following error:

```
* What went wrong: A problem occurred evaluating project ':blablabla'.
> Cannot change dependencies of configuration ':blablabla:classpath' after it has been resolved.
```

This buildscript is mandatory for both of them since i need to get 2 scenarios working:

1. When both of them could be built independently
2. When `blablabla` is treated as a sub-project of the first one.

So, the question is how can i override (or disable) buildscript section of the project being included one?

**EDIT**:

I do have following configuration:

```
// mainProject's build.gradle

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlinVersion"
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.intellij' version "0.0.36"
}

// Some other irrelevant stuff
```

`blablabla`s `build.gradle`

```
// subProject's build.gradle

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlinVersion"
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.intellij' version "0.0.36"
}

// Some other irrelevant stuff
```

And `settings.gradle`:

```
// settings.gradle

include ":subProject"
```

Comment: How are you including project2 as subproject of project1?

Comment: Properly: inside `settings.gradle` i do: `include :blablabla`

Comment: Could you please provide an example that reproduces the problem?

Comment: @Opal added to the post.

Comment: How directory structure looks like?

Comment: It doesn't matter whether subproject (`blablabla`) is nested or not.

Answer (score 0):

Digging around for some time finally found plausible solution: you can simply cut off the `buildscript` section in your *sub-project* with just conditional checking whether current project is invoked as a root one:

```
if (project == rootProject) {
  buildscript { 
    // ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There were 2 changes required to get a parent project to build `some-subproject`.

In the parent project's `build.gradle` file

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile project(':some-subproject')
    ...
}
```

And in the parent project's `setting.gradle`

```
include ':some-subproject'
```